# symfony2 go on with the ajax action after authentication

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

There is an action using Ajax(such as adding a product into cart or just a like button), after user click 'add' it needs to see whether the user has been logged in. If not, redirect to login page and login, then automatically add it and update the database, then redirect to the page the user viewed. I know I could use security annotation in controller, but how would I do this in Ajax action??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller:

```
public function ajaxAction(Request $request) {
    $authorizationChecker = $this->get('security.authorization_checker'); // Symfony 2.6+:
    //In previous Symfony versions use `security.context` service instead
    if ($authorizationChecker->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY')) {
        $currentUrl = $request->get('current_url');
        $request->getSession()->set('returnUrl', $currentUrl);
        return new JsonResponse('need_to_redirect');
    }
    // Do stuff that's supposed to happen when user is logged in
    return new JsonResponse('stuff_is_done');
}
```

In your javascript:

```
$.post('ajax_url', {currentUrl: window.location.href}, function(data) {
    if(data === 'need_to_redirect') {
        // redirect to login
    } else {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

Now in your login check controller, you can check for return url in session:

```
public function loginCheckAction(Request $request) {
    //after we checked that login is valid
    if($request->getSession->has('returnUrl')) {
        return new RedirectResponse($request->getSession()->get('returnUrl'));
    } else {
        return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('homepage'));
    }
}
```

If you're using Symfony's login check, instead of controller action, you'll have to [implement your own AuthenticationSuccessHandler](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html).

Comment: Thanks. Yes I did think about it in the way you posted. But how can I finish the ajax action (persist the data) right after the valid login check and then redirect to the original page? I don't want the user to click it again after login check. Should I store the process in a session to make a "to do list" for post login check? Or there is some other way.

Comment: @gigantic2 yes, that seems like the best way to do this. After the login, check the session for things to do.